# How do I set or clear the first 3 bits using bitwise operations?

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

Let’s say I have a number like *0x448*. In binary this is *0100 0100 1000*.

How do I set the bits 1, 2 and 3 to either all 0's or all 1's using bit-wise operations?  When I say the first three, I'm counting the rightmost bit as the zero bit.

So, for example

Bits as 1's:

```
b12            b0
  0100 0100 1110
            ^^^
```

Bits as 0's:

```
b12            b0
  0100 0100 0000
            ^^^
```

I'm guessing that to set them to 1's I use bit-wise OR with a mask of 14 (0x000e)? But if that is the case, how do I do something similar for clearing the bits?

---

Related:

- [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c/) (syntax varies, but the operations are the same)

Comment: Your description of "first" bit is ambiguous. Are you referring to the Most Significant or Least Significant bits?

Comment: From some of your comments it seems like you are having a hard time determining which mask number corresponds with which binary digits.  Is  that correct?

Comment: @Mithrax et al: I formatted the question and (hopefully) clarified it a little.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have the bit setting correct: `OR` with the mask of the bits you want to set.

Bit clearing bits is very similar: `AND` with the ones-complement of the bits you want cleared.

Example: Word of `0x0448`.

Settings bits 1, 2 and 3 would be `Word OR 0x000e`:

```
    0000 0100 0100 1000 = 0x0448
 OR 0000 0000 0000 1110 = 0x000e
    ---- ---- ---- ----
  = 0000 0100 0100 1110 = 0x044e
```

Clearing bits 1, 2 and 3 would be `Word AND 0xfff1`:

```
    0000 0100 0100 1000 = 0x0448
AND 1111 1111 1111 0001 = 0xfff1
    ---- ---- ---- ----
  = 0000 0100 0100 0000 = 0x0440
```

Elaborating on the ones-complement, the AND pattern for clearing is the logical NOT of the OR pattern for setting (each bit reveresed):

```
 OR 0000 0000 0000 1110 = 0x000e
AND 1111 1111 1111 0001 = 0xfff1
```

so you can use your favorite language NOT operation instead of having to figure out both values.

Comment: @staticsan, I expanded with the bit operations to make it clearer, then +1'ed you since the answer is now so much better :-) Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing you have a mask m with bits set to 1 for all the bits you want to set or clear, and 0 otherwise:

- clear bits: x & (~m)
- set bits:   x | m
- flip bits:  x ^ m

If you are only interested in one bit, in position p (starting at 0), the mask is simple to express m = 1 << p

Note that I am using C-style conventions, where:

- ~ is the 1-complement: ~10001010 = 01110101
- & is the bitwise AND
- | is the bitwise OR
- ^ is the bitwise XOR
- << is the left bit shift: 10001010 << 2 = 00101000

Comment: @Varkhan, I think you mean ~ is the ones-complement. Twos-complement of n is -n (~n + 1 from memory).

Answer (score 1):

OR with 1 is always true; AND with 0 is always false. :)

Comment: Right, but what would my mask be? 0x0000?  Do you see what I mean? When doing AND I need to have a mask, how do I specify zero's with just those positions as zero?

Comment: If you want to keep what you have there do AND with 1, if you want to erase what you have there, AND with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your OR 0x14 is correct, clearing would be:

AND (NOT 0x14)

Answer (score 0):

For clearing the bits, use AND with 0x440.

Comment: That would work with 0x0448 but not any other number - you need 0xfff1 to leave all the other bits untouched.

Answer (score 0):

```
number &= ~0xe
```

Comment: Yeah.  Too bad there's no 'n' literal modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s make sure that bits are counted from 0 starting at the right side or least significant bit and going left. Then observe this:

```
 1 <<p puts 1 at the position p, for example

 1 <<3     = 00001000

 1 <<p - 1 puts 1 at all positions up to p, exclusive
 1 <<3-1=00000111
```

The last step produced a mask to clear bits from the most significant to p inclusive. You can invert it with tilde to clear the other half.